# Slow disk access time in fresh OS X installation

Tags: macos, hard-drive

My apple-shipped disk on my frankenstein early 2011 MacBook Pro (with upgraded motherboard to 512MB GPU Memory) just gone bad and I have to replace it. I had replaced DVD drive with SSD with the old harddrive replacing the DVD bay for around 6 months.

I put a HGST disk I pulled out of a brand new ThinkPad E130 and it seems to be undetected and even OS boot menu comes up very slowly. I put a brand new WD and it is detected just fine but benchmark indicates about 1MB/s speed.

The repair shop (not official store) indicated that my bay is bad and replaced the bay and associated cables with a brand new one. The benchmark is okay with around 100MB/s speed but normal usage of the drive seems to be the same. Bootcamp installation, however, can use the disk just fine with around 60MB/s speed copying Left 4 Dead vpk files (large files) to an ExFAT partition.

I cleanly reinstalled OS X 10.9 using OS X recovery partition to format, download and install 10.9 and it seems that the issue still persists. A simple `ls` of ExFAT partition with 28 files took over 28 seconds but subsequent runs become fast.

Another partition of the harddrive is an empty HFS+ one. A simple new directory & move to trash is also very slow.

I tried resetting of SMC and NVRAM but it doesn't help.

What should I do to fix this slow disk access?

Comment: I'm sorry but what are you exactly asking now?

Comment: What should I fix this symtomps of slow disk access?